# Eagle: supply pin vcc overwritten with more than one signal

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

in some words, my circuit is feeded from battery (VBATT). The VBATT is taken with a voltage divider for read voltage by Atmega, and is routed into a voltage regulator (from 0.8/3.2 to 3.3) VREG.

All net for voltage and GND have their names and labels (I need "only" to do the signal routes and voltage divider) as you can see.

Checking for errors, DRC errors complains with

**supply pin vcc overwritten with more than one signal**

This is the image (if needed I can also give sch and brd)

On board all airwires seems ok, instead.

[image]

Thank you for your effort and support.

Comment: Is the direction of the VCC pin in the ATMega symbol set to `sup`? If so, you should change it to `pwr`.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what is says.

You have several VCC pins. One is connected to Vbat (on the supply symbol) and the others to Vreg, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference in all those supplies? Normally Analg Supplies are filtered version of the input supply. 
Again, I am not pretty sure what exactly your question is but if you are getting any kind of simulating or compiling error then that, could be because you have named the same node for different names or off page connectors. If you just want to run the simulation, try renaming all these to same name.

Comment: I reproduced this error by simply copying what you have on your schematic. I then removed all references to VBATT, but the ERC error still occurred! Saved schematic, quitted Eagle, reloaded and the error was gone.