# FT230 Schematic

Tags: eaglecad, ftdi

It might be an easy thing, but I don't understand the following setup: There is the Pin 3V3OUT that acts as source. But at the same time, the pin is connected to the 3.3V source as well. I recreated that setup in EAGLE and I get an ERC error that the 3.3V source has a double name. Aside from that, why is a source on the chip connected with another 3.3V source?

And is the 3.3V on the JP5 Connector then also connected with the same 3.3V source?

Thank you everyone,

[image]

[image]

Comment: *the pin is connected to the 3.3V source as well* - it is not connected to the source. It *is* the source. You should not connect this rail to any other 3.3V.

Comment: Hm, okay. yes of course that make sense. But why do I get the Error by ERC as shown above then? I connected with 3V3OUT on the chip and named the net 3.3V

Comment: possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/327072/eagle-supply-pin-vcc-overwritten-with-more-than-one-signal mostlikely u mixed up the pin settings. You have to define if a pin is an IN or OUT pin.

Comment: Yes, I saw that question, Christian, but I need these too symbols there, right? I connected and named the nets respectivly, but i dont understand why I get the ERC error then

Comment: You can try to use the NAME command to check the name of the nets. Maybe there is something fishy. Or try to redraw the lines.

Comment: Yup good point, but all net names are correct. It seems to be because of the PIN on the IC. hm...

Comment: Then check the symbol pin directions and use the SHOW command to check for all connections.

Comment: @ChristianB.I checked both (the pin on the IC) and the 3.3V symbol. Both show "SUP" as direction. Does this cause problems? Shouldn't only the 3.3V pin on the IC of direction "supply"?

Comment: _sup_ is a power output. _pwr_ is a power input. So except for 3V3OUT all other power pins should be set to _pwr_

Comment: @ChristianB.That's what I was assuming too. When I changed the direction of the 3.3V pin to PWR and set 3V3OUT to SUP, EAGLE demands a footprint for the 3.3V pin, which is of course not there as it is just the schematic. How would you solve that?